# What do you type to see a list of files that have changed in a svn repo?

Tags: svn, shell

I have a repo, and I want to run a standard test before updating the source on a server, that it must first check if any of the files have changed. How can I see such a list?

Comment: changed respect to what? Respect to the repository or respect to the last time you update your local version?

Comment: If the repo is checked out, and any changes are made to the checked out copy... then I need to know that.

Comment: so you can forget the option `-u`

Answer (score 2):

Gives list of locally modified files:

```
   svn st | grep "^M"
```

Answer (score 1):

The typical way is to use `svn status` and grep. Grep will return 0 if at least one line is found. For example:

Checking whether a file has been modified:

```
value=`svn status | grep -q "^M"`
```

Checking whether there is any change at all:

```
value=`svn status | grep -q "^[A-Z]"`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
svn st
```

st is short for status.
If you want to check only the modified files.

```
svn st | grep M
```

Comment: `grep M` is not good, suppose you have a file with `M` in the name

Comment: yes, but it works for me.  It won't work only if you have hundreds of changed file.  In that case you need to use some regexp.

Comment: the option `-q` is the easiest solution

Answer (score 0):

To look only to the modified items respect to the last time you update the local version

```
svn status -q
```

if you want to look to the differences between the remote repository use `-u`

```
svn status -qu
```

The option `-q` show only the modified / added / removed items